# Dropdown Navigation Menu Using Javascript in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, navigation, drop-down-menu

I've been working on a wordpress site for an internship and I'm wanting to embed javascript code in a page to create a dropdown menu that navigates the browser to the selected page.

I'm wondering, is there something special you need to do to allow js to work in a wp page? 
I tried the following code embedded in the page using the html side of posting option:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function menu_goto( menuform )
{
    // see http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/navigation.shtml
    // for an explanation of this script and how to use it on your
    // own site

    var baseurl = "173.236.164.86/where-to-buy/" ;
    selecteditem = menuform.newurl.selectedIndex ;
    newurl = menuform.newurl.options[ selecteditem ].value ;
    if (newurl.length != 0) {
      top.location.href = baseurl + newurl ;
    }
}
//-->
</script>

<form action="dummyvalue">
<select name="newurl" onchange="menu_goto(this.form)">
<option value="" selected="selected">----- Select A Product -----</option>
<option value="vene-prototype-version/">VENE Prototype Version</option>
<option value="configuration-vene-version/">VENE Configuration Version</option>
<option value="customized-vene-version/"> VENE Customized Version</option>
</select>
</form>
```

The dropdown menu appears, but fails to redirect the browser on change.
I have tried surrounding the code in the page with the   tags and that has no effect either.

http://173.236.164.86/where-to-buy/

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer Tools show a parse error in your JS. Probably from WP automatically inserting paragraph returns. Remove all the white space and carriage returns in the JS and try it.